# Accessing other users google calendar through google calendar api

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I just creating an application where i could be able to access other users calendar behalf of the user and create events. What I want to achieve is access my calendar via api and should be able to create events. Meanwhile managers should be able to remove my created event if any need arise in future.

I tried to do this via OAuth tokens and using tokens i was able to create events. Also giving an ACL permission to the calendar i was able to remove the event from the users calendar as a manager. But Without connecting to the google calendar I should be able to access users event and delete it. How can I approach this issue. Do I need to take any solution with service accounts?

I would appreciate your answers. Thank you.

Comment: not sure I understand the issue sounds like you have it working already

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.